# Ball to Ball Collision resolution Stick together

Tags: c++, graphics, collision-detection, glm-math

If have the following code which simulates a ball to Ball collision. My problem is, that the balls bounce against each other. I want to have the balls stick together like snow particles. Does anyone know how to do that?

```
/**
 * Rotates coordinate system for velocities
 *
 * Takes velocities and alters them as if the coordinate system they're on was rotated
 *
 * @param  Object | velocity | The velocity of an individual particle
 * @param  Float  | angle    | The angle of collision between two objects in radians
 * @return Object | The altered x and y velocities after the coordinate system has been rotated
 */

glm::vec3 rotateVel(glm::vec3 vel, float angle) {
    glm::vec3 rotatedVelocities = {
        vel.x * std::cos(angle) - vel.y * std::sin(angle),
        vel.x * std::sin(angle) + vel.y * std::cos(angle),
        0
    };

    return rotatedVelocities;
}

/**
 * Swaps out two colliding particles' x and y velocities after running through
 * an elastic collision reaction equation
 *
 * @param  Object | particle      | A particle object with x and y coordinates, plus velocity
 * @param  Object | otherParticle | A particle object with x and y coordinates, plus velocity
 * @return Null | Does not return a value
 */

void resolveCollision(Particle& particle, Particle& otherParticle) {
    float xVelocityDiff = particle.speed.x - otherParticle.speed.x;
    float yVelocityDiff = particle.speed.y - otherParticle.speed.y;

    float xDist = otherParticle.pos.x - particle.pos.x;
    float yDist = otherParticle.pos.y - particle.pos.y;

    // Prevent accidental overlap of particles
    if (xVelocityDiff * xDist + yVelocityDiff * yDist >= 0) {

        // Grab angle between the two colliding particles
        float angle = -std::atan2(otherParticle.pos.y - particle.pos.y, otherParticle.pos.x - particle.pos.x);

        // Store mass in var for better readability in collision equation
        float m1 = particle.mass;
        float m2 = otherParticle.mass;

        // Velocity before equation
        glm::vec3 u1 = rotateVel(particle.speed, angle);
        glm::vec3 u2 = rotateVel(otherParticle.speed, angle);

        // Velocity after 1d collision equation
        glm::vec3 v1(u1.x * (m1 - m2) / (m1 + m2) + u2.x * 2 * m2 / (m1 + m2),
            u1.y,
            0.0);
        glm::vec3 v2(u2.x * (m1 - m2) / (m1 + m2) + u1.x * 2 * m2 / (m1 + m2),
            u2.y,
            0.0);

        // Final velocity after rotating axis back to original location
        glm::vec3 vFinal1 = rotateVel(v1, -angle);
        glm::vec3 vFinal2 = rotateVel(v2, -angle);

        // Swap particle velocities for realistic bounce effect
        particle.speed.x = vFinal1.x *0.5;
        particle.speed.y = vFinal1.y * 0.5;

        otherParticle.speed.x = vFinal2.x * 0.5;
        otherParticle.speed.y = vFinal2.y * 0.5;
    }
}
```

I understand the code but don't know where to change it to get the result I want.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be an OpenGL problem (OpenGL is not involved in the code). Probably you just have to set the speed of both colliding particles to the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
void resolveCollision(Particle& particle, Particle& otherParticle) {
    float xVelocityDiff = particle.speed.x - otherParticle.speed.x;
    float yVelocityDiff = particle.speed.y - otherParticle.speed.y;

    float xDist = otherParticle.pos.x - particle.pos.x;
    float yDist = otherParticle.pos.y - particle.pos.y;

    // Prevent accidental overlap of particles
    if (xVelocityDiff * xDist + yVelocityDiff * yDist >= 0) {

        // Grab angle between the two colliding particles
        float angle = -std::atan2(otherParticle.pos.y - particle.pos.y, otherParticle.pos.x - particle.pos.x);

        // Store mass in var for better readability in collision equation
        float m1 = particle.mass;
        float m2 = otherParticle.mass;

        // Velocity before equation
        glm::vec3 u1 = rotateVel(particle.speed, angle);
        glm::vec3 u2 = rotateVel(otherParticle.speed, angle);

        // Velocity after 1d collision equation
        glm::vec3 v1(u1.x * (m1 - m2) / (m1 + m2) + u2.x * 2 * m2 / (m1 + m2),
            u1.y,
            0.0);
        glm::vec3 v2(u2.x * (m1 - m2) / (m1 + m2) + u1.x * 2 * m2 / (m1 + m2),
            u2.y,
            0.0);

        // Final velocity after rotating axis back to original location
        glm::vec3 vFinal1 = rotateVel(v1, -angle);
        glm::vec3 vFinal2 = rotateVel(v2, -angle);

        // Swap particle velocities for realistic bounce effect
        particle.speed.x = vFinal1.x;
        particle.speed.y = vFinal1.y;

        otherParticle.speed.x = vFinal1.x;
        otherParticle.speed.y = vFinal1.y;
    }
}
```

This solution worked for me.